# Razor Layout with model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a layout which it has two partial views, one for LogIn and one for Register.

```
//Login (In layout)
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
and in the partial
@model LogOnVM

///register (in layout)
@Html.Partial("_RegisterPartial")
and in the partial
@model RegisterVM
```

As it shown, both of them have different Models.

My problem is that when I am trying to add one more view(with different model) that is derived from this layout  I am getting the following error

> The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type 'HomeVM', but
>   this dictionary requires a model item
>   of type 'LogOnVM'.

How could I render the partials in the layout without having any problem with the other views?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I found a solution.

Instead of calling the partials with `RenderPartial`, I have created two `ActionResult` methods in `Account` Controller:

1. One for LogIn (`LoginPartial`)
2. One for register (`RegisterPartial`).

Then in layout I call them with `RenderAction()`:

```
Html.RenderAction("LoginPartial", "Account");
Html.RenderAction("RegisterPartial", "Account");
```

I don't know if it is the best approach for performance but it works fine.